# Why are JS factories/closures so much slower than constructors/prototypes?

Tags: v8, spidermonkey, javascriptcore

Once upon a time, factories/closures in JS were within 15-ish percent of constructors/prototypes. Today, the difference is over 8000% in favor of prototypes (and prototypes use about half the memory).

https://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-factory-performance/4

Closures (in theory) don't create more objects. You have the closure and the instance instead of the prototype and the instance (and closures have another advantage because you can't add/remove properties from them). My only conclusion is that even though functions are primitives and immutable (though function objects are not), they are not interned causing instruction cache thrashing jumping around. This difference appears to be across JS engines.

Does anyone have any actual facts about why this huge disparity is there?

Answer (score 1):

> Closures (in theory) don't create more objects.

This style of "closure/factory" object creation does create more objects: using prototypes, the instances of the prototype methods are shared, whereas in the "factory" style, each object instance gets its own copy of all the methods. This is observable, so it's not something that the engine can just optimize away. Consider:

```
var x1 = createValueObject();
var x2 = createValueObject();
x1.get.my_tag = 42;
console.log(x2.get.my_tag);      // undefined
console.log(x2.get === x1.get);  // false

var y1 = new ValueObject();
var y2 = new ValueObject();
y1.get.my_tag = 123;
console.log(y2.get.my_tag);      // 123
console.log(y2.get === y1.get);  // true
```

I'd like to emphasize that in general, using closures and factories is perfectly fine; this point here only applies to *this particular pattern* of creating objects.

---

> https://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-factory-performance/4

This is also a great example of: **Beware of misleading microbenchmarks!**

Whenever you see hundreds of millions of ops/sec in a jsperf.com benchmark, then almost certainly the optimizing compiler managed to eliminate all your code and you're measuring empty loops. No actual operation is that fast.

That's not surprising in this case: using prototypes is *the* idiomatic way to define/create objects in JavaScript, and engines have been investing lots of effort into optimizing every aspect of that pattern, so modern engines have the ability to track which prototype methods are getting called, inline them eventually (not immediately, only in hot code!), figure out that they don't produce useful results, and drop all the useless code.

With a proper, careful benchmark, I would expect that what you call the "constructors/prototypes" pattern is still significantly faster, but not quite as fast as the current results misleadingly indicate.

---

> instruction cache thrashing

No, the instruction cache has nothing to do with this.

> Once upon a time, factories/closures in JS were within 15-ish percent of constructors/prototypes.

I have a hard time believing that was the case any time in the past ten years. Maybe 20 years ago, when everything was dog slow?

Comment: Why would copies of the functions be necessary? Wouldn't a pointer to an interned function would allow sharing of the same function across objects? Since the shape of the resulting literals is identical and occurs at the same point in the code, shouldn't sharing a hidden class be possible?

If you're iterating dozens of identical functions with different locations in memory constantly swapping in and out of cache, isn't that thrashing the cache compared to running the same 5-6 functions repeatedly?

Comment: As the code snippet demonstrates, having copies of the function objects is observable (programs could rely on this); in other words, the JavaScript spec demands that there must be copies. Their *code* will be shared in most engines (hence no instruction cache effects), but the objects must be separate. Hidden classes do not change this.